# Why Does My Page Not Display In The Right Size On An Android Even With Viewport/Media Queries?

Tags: android, html, css, android-layout, mobile

Okay So the website in question is this:

Now if you notice on this website, the resolution of the white background div is 445px across y 686px long. It's also fluid so if you shrink it, it will appear different to accomdate different sizes. (if you are on a cell phone that has a smaller width than 400px, it will actually show different images).

Okay, but the point is here is that this page is not showing right on android devices as shown below.

[image]

That phone, along with all the other phones in that previewer that are 480px x 800px are displaying the website like that. The website, as you can see if you click on it, is a max of 686px tall, so why the heck isn't the whole page showing on this mobile device?

The size of that "playplanet" logo is actually 180px across and it almost fills up the whole width and the width of that phone is SUPPOSED to be 480px across.

Am I missing something here?

If you look at the source code, you'll see I added the following meta tags:

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

These are supposed to tell the android browser to display the page as the actual width of the device, so it should be telling it to make it show as 480px X 800px (samsung galaxy s 2 is 480px X 800px), but in reality if you look at the screenshot, it is actually displaying it as HALF that size since the logo is only 180px and its almost filled up the whole screen.

It should fit in there perfectly. The funny thing is actually my smaller than 400px width layout works perfectly on the smaller feature phone sizes (240 x 320 or vice versa), but this bigger one is causing me problems.

Comment: Look at 'Defining Viewport Size' http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html which states that the browser defaults to "overview mode" by default (800 pixels).

Comment: yeah overview mode means its zoomed out. i did add the viewport, as you can see above which SHOULD remove the overview mode. the problem here is that it's so zoomed in.. it makes droid device look like its not actually 480px across, but maybe about half of it, when the viewport i added should make it 480, not half. do u see what im saying?

Comment: the logo i have above makes the droid device actually look like its maybe 200px across, when the device i'm using is actualyl 480px across

Comment: Have you tried it on an actual phone and not just your Mobile testing program? Maybe it's a glitch in there.

Comment: i doubt it.. its a paid service. and no i dont have any phone, maybe ill goto the phone store and test it tho lol good idea

Comment: Instead of `width=device-width` try `width=460` (or any number close to that). Interested to see if that makes any difference...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried `target-densityDpi=device-dpi`?

Quoting from [this article](http://darkforge.blogspot.it/2010/05/customize-android-browser-scaling-with.html): Android team has implemented a custom meta viewport property to allow you to customize browser scaling for high resolution (HDPI) screens. The CSS "px" unit may differ from a device's actual pixels, as the browser "scales" images and fonts to a larger size than you requested. Worse, it's using a non-integer scaling factor (e.g. 1.5x zoom, to scale 320px to 480px) which makes images look really weird.

Also, in this [introduction to meta viewport](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/) the example below the section "Setting the target density" looks like your case.

Here is the updated meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densityDpi=device-dpi">
```

Comment: This. A pixel is not a pixel, and 480x800 phones are, in browser, 320x5xx. (http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html)

Comment: okay... so what am i supposed to use to scale things or make them the way i want? i understand the concept of dpi, but this still doesn't answer how the best way to style it is

Comment: if px's don't work... then  what? how do you do fonts withotu pixels? thats all they operate in. i know about "ems", but isn't ems just how many multiplied times a pixel size, so in reality its just a different way of saying this is x amt of px's size?

Comment: and if its DPI, okay... so how am i supposed to deal with styling all these different dpis? i read the link you gave.. very vague on design.

Comment: @sab to deal with them, just add the meta i gave you, no need to scale. That will handle the different DPIs ( http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#resolution0 ) and render your page the same way even on displays which have an higher pixel density. An `em` isn't related to single pixels, but to font-size: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot you are looking at is flawed.  It is displaying your site at a 240px x 400px resolution that is typical of many of the standard LG and Samsung smartphones. The Galaxy *[as you point out]* obviously has a higher resolution then that.  My suggestion would be to report the bug to the service that you are using and until they correct it, try using another similar phone to test with.  Any other android phone with the right resolution should work, as webpages are pretty much displayed the same for every single android device sans the resolution and orientation.